# Changing an image with a click (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

So, I'm working on a project for a motion-graphics class, wherein they teach us no JavaScript but then have us make a webpage using JavaScript. We're told to use DreamWeaver, and that's worked okay for most things, but I'm having trouble with one function in particular-

I want to be able to change an image multiple times when it is clicked. I've put the DW generated code below, basically I want sun.png to change to whitedwarf.png when clicked, and that works fine using the MM_swapImage() method. The rub is that I want to be able to click on the new whitedwarf.png and change it to a 3rd image (planet.png for the curious).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 100px;
background-image: url(Images/startile.gif);
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src;     x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="Images/sun.png" width="500" height="500" id="Image1" onclick="MM_swapImage('Image1','','Images/whitedwarf.png',0)" />
</body>
</html>
```

I've provided as much relevant info as I can, I have precisely no familiarity with JS, though I have programmed a good deal in Java, so I'm not completely illiterate.

Comment: Like I said, we're instructed to use DreamWeaver rather than learning the actual language, so I work with what I've been given.

Comment: What is the variable `parent` supposed to be?

Comment: @David - It's the `window.parent` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand its even worse when you have no familiarity with JS. I'll try to clean it up a bit.

Comment: I feel moderately confident that I just need to modify the MM_swapImage() to support 3 instead of just 2 images. I just have no idea how to do that because this code was written by DreamWeaver.

Comment: @user1265486 don't forget to mark as answer the answer that solved your problem (or helped you the most) by clicking the green check to the left of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Use Dreamweaver"? Phooey on Dreamweaver. You don't need no stinkin Dreamweaver.

Start with a collection of images grouped inside a `div` or `section` (if you're using HTML5)
If CSS or Javascript are disabled, the images will show up normally, so you can still see them all.

```
<div id="imgs">
<img src="img.jpg" alt="My Image 1"/>
<img src="img2.jpg" alt="My Image 2"/>
</div>
```

Then, when the page loads, hide all the images except one, and wire a click event to each image to hide itself and display the next one.

```
var port_imgs, i;
    window.onload = function () {
            //get all the images in "#imgs"
        port_imgs = document.getElementById("imgs").getElementsByTagName("img");
           //loop through, hiding them all
        for (i = 0; i < port_imgs.length; i++) {
            port_imgs[i].style.display = "none";
                    //wire up the click event and do the magic
            port_imgs[i].onclick = (function (k) {
                var r = function () {
                    this.style.display = "none";
                    if (k >= port_imgs.length) { k = 0 }
                    port_imgs[k].style.display = "block";
                };
                return r;
            })(i+1);
        }
            //un-hide (display) the first image so we're all set to go
        port_imgs[0].style.display = "block";
    }
```

You can see a live example on my [website](http://thomasshields.net/web), where I've employed exactly the same thing.

Comment: So, you ID the div as "images" but the array seems to call "imgs". Is there a difference? I feel very much like I'm missing a piece.

Comment: ack, sorry. my bad, typo. It was called "portfolio" on my site and that didn't make sense here, so i changed it, but i changed it to two different things. edited.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the list of images in an array and then switching the src of the image element on click, like this.

```
i = 0
var images = ['Images/sun.png', 'Images/whitedwarf.png', 'Images/planet.png']
function MM_swapImage() {
 if(i >= images.length)
  {
    img = document.getElementById('Image1')
    img.setAttribute('onclick','')
    return

 }
 img = document.getElementById('Image1')
 img.setAttribute('src',images[i])
 i = i+1
}
```

Comment: I'm about to try this. Looking at it, I assume that would replace the MM_swapImage() body?

Comment: Yes if you replace your function and change the image array it should work

Comment: If I remove the i = 0 after the function name, will it not loop?
(apart from looping, which I want to disable, this works great- thanks so much)

Comment: Should no longer loop, you could also just return in the if statement, but this way the onclick function will no longer be called

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript

```
function onClickFunction(){

    var imageSRC = document.getElementById("Image1").src = "whitedwarf.png"
}
```

Using jQuery

```
function onClickFunction(){
    $("#Image1").attr("src", "whitedwarf.png");
}
```

Comment: So, I'm not afraid to look stupid- won't that just give me the same image over and over? Using JS, how do I change the "whitedwarf.png" to a different filename via clicking?

Comment: Yes! That is correct. I just add the code for changing it once. You can toogle the image, like this:

Comment: function onClickFunction(){
    var imageSRC = document.getElementById("Image1").src;
    if(imageSRC == "sun.png"){
        imageSRC = "whitedwarf.png";
    }else{
        imageSRC = "sun.png";
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty version of that functionality that is actually readable for humans:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        background-image: url(Images/startile.gif);
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Images = {
      library: ['Images/sun.png', 'Images/whitedwarf.png', 'Images/planet.png'],
      swap: function (element) {
        var elementSrc = element.src,
            i = 0,
            libLength = this.library.length,
            src = false;
        for(; i < libLength; i++) {
          src = this.library[i];
          if(src === elementSrc) {
            element.setAttribute('src', this.library[(i+1) % libLength]);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
   </head>

  <body>
    <img src="Images/sun.png" width="500" height="500" id="Image1" onclick="Images.swap(this)" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Using this code, you can add an arbitrary number of images by adding their url into the `Images.library`-array. I've provided a jsFiddle (an HTML, JS and CSS playground) as a proof of concept.

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/L6DW9/

**EDIT** I also edited in the missing piece of the HTML page, in case you just copied the whole thing.

**EDIT2**: To skip the wrap around, Change `swap: function () {[...]}` to this:

```
swap: function (element) {
    var elementSrc = element.src,
        i = 0,
        libLength = this.library.length,
        src = false;
    for(; i < libLength; i++) {
        src = this.library[i];
        if(src === elementSrc) {
            if((i+1) >= libLength) {
               element.onclick = false;
            }
            element.setAttribute('src', this.library[(i+1) % libLength]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this out, and it actually loaded my images (the other proposed solutions havent) but when I click, nothing seems to happen. Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: Have you checked that the paths that I entered are correct? i.e: `Images/whitedwarf.png` and `Images/planet.png`

Comment: Yes, it finds the first file with no problems, it just doesn't change after a click. And I triple-checked for typos, the paths match up.

Comment: In case you just copied my code and replace the whole page, i've added in the missing markup parts.

Comment: This works, I'm not sure what my prior problem was, all I did was replace the MM_swapImage() with your method and change the onclick =""
Either way, this achieves my goal. Thanks for putting up with my ignorance.

Comment: Did you want to not have a wrap-around?

Comment: I did. I'm currently fiddling about with your framework and malbani's trying to figure that part out.

Comment: See my edit. If you replace the `swap`-function with this new one, you won't see any wrap around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elegant solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/H5fPT/

```
(function() {
    var Main = {
        images: [],
        idx: 0,

        fillArray: function(arr) {
            if (typeof arr == "object") {
                if (arr.length) {
                    Main.images = Main.images.concat(arr);
                } else Main.images.push(arr);
            } else {
                if (arguments.length) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                        Main.images.push(arguments[i]);
                    }
                } else return;
            }
        },
        changeImage: function(el, n) {
            el.src = Main.images[Main.idx];
            Main.idx += n;
        }
    };

    var a = [
        'http://bit.ly/sbK2Ub',
        'http://bit.ly/yYi5oQ',
        'http://bit.ly/4GjHJn'
    ];
    var b = document.getElementById('g'),
        c = document.getElementById('e');

    Main.fillArray(a);

    b.onclick = function() {
        Main.changeImage(c, 1);
    };
})();​
```

Use `Main.fillArray(arr);` to fill the array with images and use `Main.changeImage(el, n);` where `el` is the image element whose `src` will change and `n` is the amount of images you want to skip over (in your case, 3).